# Remote command via SSH not working

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote

I tried to send the following but it is not working. Anyone have any idea?

> ssh user@host "date; ls -l"

If I login to the host and run the command then it worked

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 1.2.3.4 ([1.2.3.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: date; ls -l
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to 1.2.3.4 closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 2864, received 2200 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 21770.4, received 16723.1
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Comment: If you do something like `ssh user@host "date > /tmp/date.out"` and then login interactively, has the file been created?

Comment: It didn't get created.